# Amann, Escher - Continuous extensions

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, metric-spaces

This is from Amann-Escher *Analysis I*.

For metric spaces $X,Y$, a subset $D \subseteq X$, a limit point $a$ of $D$ and a function $f\colon D\to Y$, they define $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = y$, if for each sequence $(x_n)$ in $D$ which converges to $a$ in $X$, the sequence $(f(x_n))$ converges too $y$ in $Y$. They then prove that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = y$ if and only if for each neighborhood $V$ of $y$ in $Y$ there is a neighborhood $U$ of of $a$ in $X$ such that $f(U\cap D) \subseteq V$.

After that, the following theorem follows:

> Let $X,Y$ be metric spaces, $D$ a subset of $X$, $a$ a limit point of $D$ contained in $X\setminus D$ and $f\colon D\to Y$ a continuous function. Let $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = y$. Then the function $\overline{f}\colon D\cup\{a\}\to Y$ such that $\overline{f}{\restriction_D} = f$ and $\overline{f}(a) = y$ is continuous.

They say that it suffices to prove that that $\overline{f}$ is continuous at $a$, which is clear. However, what is not clear to me is why it is continuous at $x \in D$ even if $f$ is.

Indeed, let $x \in D$ and let $V$ be a neighborhood of $f(x)$. Then there is open subset $O$ of $X$ such that $f(O\cap D) \subseteq V$, that is, $\overline{f}(O\cap D) \subseteq V$. What I don't see is how it follows from that $f(O\cap (D\cup \{a\}) \subseteq V$ since $V$ doesn't have to contain $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\in D$, let $x_n\in D\cup\{a\}$ such that $lim_n x_n=a$. There exists $N$ such that $n>N$ implies that that $x_n\neq a$, otherwise we can extract a subsequence such that $x_{n_q}=a$ and $lim$ $x_{n_q}=lim$ $x_n=a$, contradiction since $a$ is not in $D$. $lim_n\bar f(x_n)=lim_{n>N}\bar f(x_n)=lim_{n>N}f(x_n)=f(x)$ since $f$ is continuous on $D$.